# Is there a way to avoid the AVD start screen?

Tags: android

By default, when you start the AVD, you need to watch for a feel long seconds a start screen that shows "Android" on it, is there a way to avoid it? write or delete a simple command line?

Comment: No, there isn't any way to it. In that time, AVD system version config is loaded.

Comment: I think this would be roughly akin to asking if you can remove the boot animation on your phone. Technically, I suppose it could be done, but the alternative is looking at a blank screen for the same amount of time.

Comment: To expand on gobernador's comment, that boot animation/logo isn't just there to annoy you. While that animation is showing, the phone (or virtual device) is busy starting up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the possibility of saving the state of the emulator to a snapshot and loading from it the next time you start. Start up time will be cut really short this way, although not completely eliminated. However, be aware that the emulator will be in the same state you left it in last time you shut it down, with all the running processes and such.

To enable snapshots on an AVD (if using the AVD Manager in Eclipse) : Select a device, press Edit and under Snapshots select Enable (it's roughly in the middle of the window).
After that if you press Start, you will see that the options Load from and Save to a snapshot are enabled for selection.

The first time you do this it will have to boot up the usual way (since there is no snapshot available), but next time you start, you should see a speed up if using the snapshot.

You can choose whether to let it run a full boot or just run from the snapshot every time you run the device at your will.